# How to run specific Cypress tests with environment variables set on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, automated-tests, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner

I do a bunch of automation tests in Cypress. My project CI/CD is on Gitlab.
I need to have a possibility to set up environment variable in Gitlab->Pipelines with the list of specific tests which I would like to run ("Test1, Test2").
I added the following to the index.js:

```
beforeEach(function() {

  const testFilter = Cypress.env('TEST_FILTER');
  if (!testFilter) {
    return;
  }
  
  const testName = Cypress.mocha.getRunner().test.fullTitle();
  cy.log("beforeEach1");
  if (!testName.includes(testFilter)) {
    cy.log("beforeEach2");
    this.skip();
  }
})
```

Then I updated my `.gitlab-ci.yml` with:

```
- TEST_FILTER: sampleTest.feature
```

And finally I have :

```
"cy:open": "cypress open",
"cy:filter:implicit": "set CYPRESS_TEST_FILTER=Implicit & cypress open",
```

However it doesn't work and when I run pipeline and add variable there on Gitlab (TEST_FILTER) I get this error:

```
Pipeline cannot be run.

Undefined error (01GDMNJ755F2J576MWPPX5Y9QQ)
```

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with this: `"cy:filter:implicit": "CYPRESS_TEST_FILTER=Implicit cypress open"`

Comment: Oh, you can get it like this `"cy:filter:implicit": "cypress open --env CYPRESS_TEST_FILTER=Implicit"`